# eclipse workspace is closed problem

Tags: java, eclipse

How to get access to eclipse workspace from java program.
When I use `IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()` it gives me exception like this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
  at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:329)
  at amdocs.amsp.test.EMFCodeGen.load(EMFCodeGen.java:37)
  at amdocs.amsp.test.EMFCodeGen.main(EMFCodeGen.java:26)
```

can you tell me how to get access to workspace from a standalone java program out side of eclipse. (of ourse there is a classpath with all the jar required for that)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do it in OSGi based application (eqinox for example)? Because workspace is created upon start of `org.eclipse.core.resources` bundle that should be managed by framework, exception of yours means that bundle probably didn't start yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this, the workspace retrieved with `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()` is the workspace the running Platform is using, if `Platform.isRunning()`. So if you are running a plain Java application, not an Eclipse application, there is no such thing as *the* workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your application like this it must be headless. Following you can see how to create a headless project:
[Going Headless](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/ppa/tut_4.html)